# Parsing an xml with AsyncTask using Http request

Tags: android, xml, parsing, dom, android-asynctask

I am making a connection to the Internet using HTTP Request, parsing an XML
Everything works correctly, but I want to do is make the connection from a AsyncTask for new versions of android sdk.
Usually should not give problems, but I am following a tutorial and after trying many options and see similar threads on this website, I can not apply it correctly.

This is the code I'm using

Activity 1:

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/music/music.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;


    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
            map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));
            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
        }

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }   
}
```

And this is the second activity:

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```

...I understand that it must be encapsulated in a AsycTask is:

```
try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
```

...But to be using strings of two activitys, I can not find a way to do

Thank you very much for the help

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this type of class as subclass in your activity:

```
 private class YourDownload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            /*
                        make connection & download XML here, 
                        use your XML parser class object to parse the xml from here

                        create ArrayList & etc. from here...

                    */
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // postexecute logic
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // pre execute logic
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

    }
```

use *YourDownload* from *onCreate()* as `new YourDownload().execute();`

Probably this will help you..

Comment: Exacto, pero el problema no es la implementación del asynctask. El problema es que cuando incluyo el código para la conexión a internet en el doInBackground, No sé como hacer que sea válido ya que la conexión a internet está dentro de un public String.

Comment: please type in english... I don't know spanish

Comment: Exactly, but the problem is not the implementation of AsyncTask. The problem is that when I include the code for the internet connection in the doInBackground, I do not know how to make it valid because the internet connection is in a public String. i use " new MiTarea().execute();" and i do not know how to implement internet connection in the doInBackground. Thanks :)

Comment: Ya implementado la lógica en varias clases (como por subido por usted) .. reunirlos y utilizarlos de manera adecuada a su aplicación en doInBackground (); Tenga en cuenta el código y el código en el "comentario" y echar un vistazo en vogella.com de AsyncTask, que le ayudará. [Thanks Google](http://translate.google.com/)